# How to translate estimated model parameters when fitting centered and scaled data?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, curves

I routinely use a non-linear curve fitting tool to fit data according to a user prescribed model / function.  One piece of advice that I commonly see around non-linear curve fitting is about data conditioning, specifically *scaling and centering*.  Consider the simple 2D model:

$y = \dfrac{a}{x^{2}} + b$

The scaled (and centered in the case of the $x$ array) arrays which can be passed to the curve fitting tool are:

$x' = \left[(x - c_{0}) / c_{1}\right] - 0.5$

$y' = (y - k_{0}) / k_{1}$

where $c_{0}$ and $k_{0}$ are minima in each series and $c_{1}$ and $k_{1}$ are the ranges.  When we perform the fit, we are fitting the model

$y' = \dfrac{a'}{x'^{2}} + b'$

The curve fitting tool returns $a'$ and $b'$.  It is straightforward to un-scale $b'$ to find $b$.

Thoughts are welcome on how to translate $a'$ to $a$.

Comment: Why not to define $t=\frac 1{x^2}$ and use $y=a t+b$ and center the $t_i$'s instead ?

Comment: Thanks @ClaudeLeibovici.  I provided a simple model here as an example.  Ultimately I'm after a general implementation so that any model can be used to fit scaled and centered data (which may not be 2D), and then the parameters can be un-scaled and un-centered.  Your suggestion is certainly valid.  Can one linearize the exponentially modified Gaussian model, for instance?

Comment: This is actually linear curve fitting: your first equation is linear in $(a,b)$, or do I miss something? There should also be an error term in your equation or is it zero (in which case the term "fitting" is not really appropriate)?

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand.  I mentioned above that the model may not be so simple as the example provided here.  Is there anything I can clarify in the question?  Would providing several examples of the non-linear functions I am fitting help?